# Google App Engine server sends data to cloud datastore even though its running through localhost:8080

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, oauth-2.0

I have a server set up to run through google app engine with java.  When I try to invoke call messages from the web UI side of the client, for some reason it will send the data to my datastore in the cloud rather than a local data store. I am using oauth2 to authenticate and the web UI asks the web UI to authenticate even if it is on a localhost:8080.

```
   /**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name oauth2Provider
 *
 * @description
 * Service that holds the OAuth2 information shared across all the pages.
 *
 */
app.factory('oauth2Provider', function ($modal) {
    var oauth2Provider = {
 ####################################.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        SCOPES: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email profile',
        signedIn: false
    };
```

The Api uses maven to fetch dependencies. I am using controllers to send the Http requests here is part of my controller.js file that shows the setup for the root App and one of the controllers. (I am getting all this code from [Udacity's Developing Scalable Apps with Java](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud859/) )

```
    /**
 * The root conferenceApp module.
 *
 * @type {conferenceApp|*|{}}
 */
var conferenceApp = conferenceApp || {};

/**
 * @ngdoc module
 * @name conferenceControllers
 *
 * @description
 * Angular module for controllers.
 *
 */
conferenceApp.controllers = angular.module('conferenceControllers', ['ui.bootstrap']);

/**
 * @ngdoc controller
 * @name MyProfileCtrl
 *
 * @description
 * A controller used for the My Profile page.
 */
conferenceApp.controllers.controller('MyProfileCtrl',
    function ($scope, $log, oauth2Provider, HTTP_ERRORS) {
        $scope.submitted = false;
        $scope.loading = false;

        /**
         * The initial profile retrieved from the server to know the dirty state.
         * @type {{}}
         */
        $scope.initialProfile = {};

        /**
         * Candidates for the teeShirtSize select box.
         * @type {string[]}
         */
        $scope.teeShirtSizes = [
            'XS',
            'S',
            'M',
            'L',
            'XL',
            'XXL',
            'XXXL'
        ];

        /**
         * Initializes the My profile page.
         * Update the profile if the user's profile has been stored.
         */
        $scope.init = function () {
            var retrieveProfileCallback = function () {
                $scope.profile = {};
                $scope.loading = true;
                gapi.client.conference.getProfile().
                    execute(function (resp) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.loading = false;
                            if (resp.error) {
                                // Failed to get a user profile.
                            } else {
                                // Succeeded to get the user profile.
                                $scope.profile.displayName = resp.result.displayName;
                                $scope.profile.teeShirtSize = resp.result.teeShirtSize;
                                $scope.initialProfile = resp.result;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                );
            };
            if (!oauth2Provider.signedIn) {
                var modalInstance = oauth2Provider.showLoginModal();
                modalInstance.result.then(retrieveProfileCallback);
            } else {
                retrieveProfileCallback();
            }
        };
```

Then I have the mapped out Api class.

```
import static com.google.devrel.training.conference.service.OfyService.ofy;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod.HttpMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.Constants;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.domain.Conference;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.domain.Profile;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ConferenceForm;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ProfileForm;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.form.ProfileForm.TeeShirtSize;
import com.google.devrel.training.conference.service.OfyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;

/**
 * Defines conference APIs.
 */
@Api(name = "conference", version = "v1", scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE }, clientIds = {
        Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID }, description = "API for the Conference Central Backend application.")
public class ConferenceApi {

    /*
     * Get the display name from the user's email. For example, if the email is
     * lemoncake@example.com, then the display name becomes "lemoncake."
     */
    private static String extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(String email) {
        return email == null ? null : email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
    }

...
...
...

    /**
     * Returns a Profile object associated with the given user object. The cloud
     * endpoints system automatically inject the User object.
     *
     * @param user
     *            A User object injected by the cloud endpoints.
     * @return Profile object.
     * @throws UnauthorizedException
     *             when the User object is null.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET)
    public Profile getProfile(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }

        // TODO
        // load the Profile Entity
        String userId = user.getUserId();
        Key key = Key.create(Profile.class, userId);

        Profile profile = (Profile) ofy().load().key(key).now();
        return profile;
    }
}
```

And the Constants class is as followed:

```
package com.google.devrel.training.conference;

import com.google.api.server.spi.Constant;

/**
 * Contains the client IDs and scopes for allowed clients consuming the conference API.
 */
public class Constants {
    public static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "###################################.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    public static final String ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your Android client ID";
    public static final String IOS_CLIENT_ID = "replace this with your iOS client ID";
    public static final String ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID;
    public static final String EMAIL_SCOPE = Constant.API_EMAIL_SCOPE;
    public static final String API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID = Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID;

    public static final String MEMCACHE_ANNOUNCEMENTS_KEY = "RECENT_ANNOUNCEMENTS";
}
```

The Html for the web UI is completely incomprehensible to me as the purpose of the Udacity class is not to develop HTML, but is like this:

```
controller="MyProfileCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="messages" class="alert alert-{{alertStatus}}" ng-show="messages">
                <span ng-bind="messages"></span>
                <i class="dismiss-messages pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="messages = ''"
                   ng-show="messages"></i>
            </div>
            <img class="spinner" src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" ng-show="loading"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h3>My Profile</h3>
            <form name="profileForm" novalidate role="form">
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-warning': profile.displayName != initialProfile.displayName}">
                    <label for="displayName">Display Name </label>
                    <span class="label label-warning"
                          ng-show="profile.displayName != initialProfile.displayName"> Changed</span>
                    <input id="displayName" type="text" name="displayName" ng-model="profile.displayName"
                           class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-warning': profile.teeShirtSize != initialProfile.teeShirtSize}">
                    <label for="teeShirtSize">Tee shirt size</label>
                    <span class="label label-warning"
                          ng-show="profile.teeShirtSize != initialProfile.teeShirtSize"> Changed</span>
                    <select id="teeShirtSize" ng-model="profile.teeShirtSize" name="teeShirtSize" ng-options="size for size in teeShirtSizes"
                            class="form-control">
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button ng-click="saveProfile(profileForm)" class="btn btn-primary"
                        ng-disabled="loading">Update profile
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The instructions in the lesson want the api to be tested locally before submitting on the server. Oddly enough, the API will create data entries to the local cloud only when I invoke calls through the APIs explorer menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well (I´m also attending the Udacity course). To me it seems to have something to do with maven - maybe the POM is outdated due to the course having been a while ago.
It took me ages to make it work and to be honest I´m not even sure how I fixed it in the end. 
Two things I did:

- check if there even is a "local_db.bin" file (the local version of the data store). It should be in /target/conference-1.0/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/. 
  But i guess this is the case as you say that the local API Explorer is working for you?
- update the SDK version in the pom.xml: 1.9.17 which was previously 1.9.3

In general I´m very happy how the course is structured but so far I had some terrible issues which I guess are related to the outdated material and there is no more support in the forums.
When I finished the course I will go ahead and also do this course:
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the same course and I was struggling with the problem. local_db.bin wasn't being created and all the changes were directly to the appspot instance uploaded. 
But fortunately after googling around I found this solution http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/136d37dqec/gae-java-1-8-1-and-broken-automatic-jetty-reload

You just add

```
<jvmFlags>
    <jvmFlag>-Dappengine.generated.dir=/tmp/blabla</jvmFlag>
</jvmFlags>
```

into the configuration part of the appengine-maven-plugin in the pom.xml file

it should look like this

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-Dappengine.generated.dir=/tmp/blabla</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now it's running perfect :)